# Exclude one file extension when starting synchronization from WinSCP command-line

Tags: synchronization, winscp

I've always used WinSCP to keep my localhost and the server syncronized while I'm working on a project and it has always worked as expected.

This is the .lnk file I've always used

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "Typed" /defaults /keepuptodate // "C:\Xampp\htdocs\my\folder\path" /my/server/path
```

Now I have to exclude .txt files, because WinSCP causes the logs on my host to be deleted (they are updated on the server but remain blank on localhost, so the sync function deletes them when I open the file).

Reading the documentation I found this solution:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "Typed" /defaults /keepuptodate // "C:\Xampp\htdocs\my\folder\path" /my/server/path /parameter // "-filemask=|*.txt"
```

The problem is that now every time I open the link I get this message:

[image: WinSCP error]

It never happened before:

- If I click on "yes", it does a full syncronization of every single
  file, even if they are already identica
- If I click "no" it does not syncronize anything, and if I change a
  file it starts syncing the whole folder

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There's no `-filemask` command-line switch.*

You have to use [raw transfer settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings) `IncludeFileMask`:

```
/rawtransfersettings IncludeFileMask="|*.txt"
```

---

Note that you use the [`//` (swo slashes)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#two_slashes). No switches work after `//`. So either put the `/rawtransfersettings` before the `//`. Or remove the `//`, unless it is really needed. It's needed if your path looks like a switch (`/path`), but not when it's clearly a path (`/my/server/path`).

Comment: Solved! As you said in the email, the `//` before the switch escaped it and caused that error.